# What is the difference between UI thread and rendering thread?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, graphics, rendering

The Microsoft docs state the following

> Typically, WPF applications start with **two threads**: one for **handling rendering** and another for managing the UI. The rendering thread effectively runs hidden in the background while the **UI thread** receives input, handles events, **paints the screen**, and runs application code.

**quote from**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/threading-model

According to the official documentation quoted above, there are 2 threads:

1. rendering thread, that does rendering
2. UI thread, that "paints the screen"?!

**What does "paints the screen" mean? Isn't it exactly the same as "rendering" which is done by the other thread?**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/framework/wpf-render-thread-failures#description-of-the-wpf-render-thread-and-how-it-differs-from-the-ui-thread is fairly informative - I *think* the UI thread tells the render thread what to draw, and the render thread turns it into pixels.

Comment: Yes, seems that's the case. Thank you! Could you please add an answer so I can upvote and accept?

Comment: I'd prefer not to, given that it would basically be a link-only answer. I'm hoping that someone who actually knows more about WPF may be ready to add a *real* answer with genuine experience :)

Answer (score 0):

WPF has two main components: one is from `user32` to interact with Windows Operating System. Another is built on `DirectX`.

```
UI Thread 
         -> Message Bumping Thread 
         -> thread processing user interaction / task queuing (on user32).
```

Rendering thread -> pixel processing (DirectX).